# SSLeay reading a PEM file

Tags: c++, openssl

I am trying to use the PEM_read_bio function to get data from a file.

The version of SSLeay we are using is from 1997, so documentation is a bit thin on the ground. Thankfully in this case it seems there is a matching function documented here: https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/PEM_read_bio.html

I originally tried this:

```
char ** names;
char ** headers;
unsigned char ** data;
long len;

BIO *in = BIO_new_file("C:\\filename.txt", "r");
if (!in)
{
    // error
}
else
{
    int result = PEM_read_bio(in, names, headers, data, &len);
}

BIO_free(in);

OPENSSL_free(names);
OPENSSL_free(headers);
OPENSSL_free(data);
```

However this results in a run-time check failure: `The variable 'names' is being used without being initialized.`

The documentation mentions `OPENSSL_malloc( num )` is used to initialize memory, but it fails to mention whether it does this behind the scenes, or the user does it.

`OPENSSL_malloc` is similar in usage to C's malloc, but how are we supposed to know how much memory to allocate in advance, before reading the file?

I have tried the following at the beginning:

```
char ** names = reinterpret_cast<char **>(OPENSSL_malloc(2));
char ** headers = reinterpret_cast<char **>(OPENSSL_malloc(2));
unsigned char ** data = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char **>(OPENSSL_malloc(2));
long len;
```

This results in apparently random data.

Comment: Wow! 1997...perhaps you should consider upgrading to a more recent version of OpenSSL!!?

Comment: Not my choice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you linked to says:

> The `name`, `header` and `data` pointers are allocated via `OPENSSL_malloc()` and **should be freed by the caller** via `OPENSSL_free()` when no longer needed.

That means `PEM_read_bio()` calls `OPENSSL_malloc()` for you, and then you call `OPENSSL_free()` on the allocated memory it returns when you are doing with it.

You are passing uninitialized pointers to `PEM_read_bio()`, that is why it is failing.  The `name`, `header` and `data` parameters are all output parameters.  You need to pass in the addresses of your own pointer variables to receive the memory that `PEM_read_bio()` allocates for you, eg:

```
char *name;
char *headers;
unsigned char *data;
long len;

BIO *in = BIO_new_file("C:\\filename.txt", "r");
if (!in)
{
    // error
}
else
{
    int result = PEM_read_bio(in, &name, &headers, &data, &len);
    if (!result)
    {
        // error
    }
    else
    {
        ...
        OPENSSL_free(name);
        OPENSSL_free(headers);
        OPENSSL_free(data);
    }
    BIO_free(in);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is obviously better than what I was trying, but I'm still not sure how to read an array of strings from the names pointer. You'd think it would involve the returned "len" but that has a strange size: 1130. I am expecting 2 names containing about 28 characters total.

In the meantime I managed to parse the PEM (.txt) file manually. I don't know whether to mark your answer as a solution considering the time you put into it.

Comment: @matt_rule the `name` value is not an array of strings. It is a single null-terminated string. Same with `headers`. The `len` only applies to the `data`. Why are you expecting an array of strings to be output for the `name`? There is only 1 name in the PEM object being read: "*When an object is successfully retrieved, the type name from the "----BEGIN <type>-----" is returned via the `name` argument, any encapsulation headers are returned in `header` and the base64-decoded content and its length are returned via `data` and `len` respectively.*"

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I now understand that the PEM_read_bio function is meant to be called several times, perhaps in a while loop, until it returns 0. A return code of 1 indicates there is more data to be read.

Comment: "*A return code of 1 indicates there is more data to be read*" - no, it means that data was successfully read for the current object. There is no indication that another object may be present. Per the documentation: "*`PEM_read()` and `PEM_read_bio()` return 1 on success and 0 on failure, the latter includes the case when no more PEM objects remain in the input file. To distinguish end of file from more serious errors the caller must peek at the error stack and check for `PEM_R_NO_START_LINE`, which indicates that no more PEM objects were found. See `ERR_peek_last_error`, `ERR_GET_REASON`.*"